# Why we need time dimension for general relativity?

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, gravity

May sound strange but why GR came up with the 4th dimension ( ct ) while same results could be obtained by making a postulate like : space ( and not spacetime ) shrinks around a mass-energy component. Let’s not forget that addition of time to space dimensions was actually a postulate.
Then we could set the shrinkage ratio compatible with Lorentz factor.
I believed everything including Schwartzchild matrix and other phenomena could be adjusted to just Cartesian 3 dimensions instead of 4.
Well , I am sure there is an explanation to that and that’s why I am asking here if anyone knows. Will pure 3D Cartesian space contraction cause an error in the physics of the manifold ?

Comment: It was Minkowski who introduced time as a fourth dimension, not Einstein.

Comment: *Will pure space contraction cause an error in the physics of the manifold?* Yes.

Comment: *they could just make a postulate* Postulates aren’t arbitrary like that. They need to lead to theoretical predictions that actually agree with experimental observations.

Comment: In short (and maybe a bit simplistic): We can restrict ourselves to SR which started as a theory better explaining electro magnetism which is based on the Maxwell equations. This leads almost inevitably to the [Loretntz transformations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivations_of_the_Lorentz_transformations), hence to transformations of space *and* time.

Comment: @Ghoster would you elaborate about which physical properties that would be affected ? ( that can be the actual answer to my question )

Comment: Two examples: You won’t get the right bending of starlight around the Sun. You won’t get the right advance of perihelion for Mercury.

Comment: It is in principle possible to have multiple theories of gravity with different features and different conceptualizations of reality that are indistinguishable in the sense that they give the same predictions. They might be of differing complexities, and have different domains of usefulness. But, (and someone correct me if I'm wrong) I'm not sure if one could be expressed purely in terms of dynamical evolution of space as opposed to being expressed in terms of the static geometry of spacetime, because the distinction between space and time cannot be established globally.

Answer (score 1):

Time is already a fourth dimension in Newtonian physics - it's just that we don't think of it as such because the time transformation in [Galilean transformations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galilean_transformation) is $t'=t$ i.e. time is the same for all observers.