# What is the reason of different clock's measurements in different frames?

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, inertial-frames, time, time-dilation

I tried to understand what is the reason of different clock's measurements in different frames.

For this I looked at easy example with distance S traveled by man with moving clock (velocity V1=2m/s) and distance traveled by man with another moving clock(velocity V2=1m/s). If clock is moving with velocity V1 then measurement T1=S/V1 and for V2 we have measurement T2=S/V2. First clock is more slowly than second clock.

It was bad example but something like example with time dilation effect where relation between velocity V and time T is more complicated (example with light clock, Pythagorean theorem).

Am I right that reason of different clock's measurements is velocity or am I missing something?

Comment: If the reason for different clock measurements were velocity we could have lived on with Newtonian mechanics and Galilean transformations forever. The ultimate reason is explained in short in [this comment](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/775624/why-we-need-time-dimension-for-general-relativity#comment1741799_775624).

Comment: @KurtG. Ok. I mean that if velocity of moving clock is zero we have same time in different frames. But if we have non-zero velocity we can use formula with complicated relation between velocity V and times in different frames.

Comment: If you mean the relationship between $t$ and $t'$ in the well-known Lorentz transformation this should be obvious.

Comment: If it takes you T seconds to cover the distance S at 2 m/s, then it takes you 2T seconds to  cover the distance S at 1 m/s. That's just due to the definition of speed. It has nothing to do with time dilation.

Comment: @PM2Ring I wrote that it was bad example. Relation between elapsed time and velocity is more complicated. (Lorentz transformation) Am I right?

Comment: @Mike_bb Let's say we have two (inertial) frames F and F', and F' is moving with constant velocity v relative to F. And we have two events (points in spacetime), A and B. In frame F, the time between A & B equals t and the distance between A & B equals s. In frame F', the time between the same A & B equals t' and the distance between A & B equals s'. The Lorentz transformation tells you how to calculate t' and s' from t, s, and v.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In physics there are two different concepts of time. “Proper time” is the physical time, denoted $\tau$, read by a good clock. Proper time is invariant, meaning that all reference frames agree on what a given clock reads. “Coordinate time” is the mathematical time, denoted $t$, used in some coordinate system. Different frames use different coordinates, so they disagree on coordinate time.

If the coordinate system is a standard inertial frame then the relationship between the two is $$c^2 d\tau^2=c^2 dt^2-dx^2-dy^2-dz^2$$$$\frac{d\tau^2}{dt^2}=1-\frac{dx^2}{c^2 dt^2}-\frac{dy^2}{c^2 dt^2}-\frac{dz^2}{c^2 dt^2}$$$$\frac{d\tau}{dt}=\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}=\frac{1}{\gamma}$$